# Can I really remove this seemingly redundant code without breaking things?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I found a snippet in our code base that looks kind of useless to me but I suspect that somebody put it there for a reason that eludes me; so I thought I'd ask around. The part is something like this:

```
someParam = 'nope'  # someParam is actually a query result, not a fixed string
if someParam != 'nope' and True or False
```

In my opinion the `and True or False` is doing exactly nothing for the evaluation and can be removed since the first part, the equality check, combined with the `and True` (operator precedence `and` > `or`, IIRC) is the same as the first part:

If first part evaluates to True -> True and True -> True

If the first part is False -> False and True -> False

now those results with the appended `or False`:

True or False -> True

False or False -> False

So the result of the condition would not change if I removed the `and True or False`, correct? Or am I missing something here?

Also could the behaviour of this change while switching from Python 2 to 3? I think not but I'm not quite sure.

Comment: try it.........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `x and True or False` can be simplified to just `x` when `x` is a boolean value.

Comment: Could have been a forgotten debugging artifact (though I cannot imagine a concrete scenario). I have difficulty imagining anyone would straight up write this without some motivation, it doesn't resemble any of the usual weirdness someone bad at coding does.

Comment: sure, but the value of the param is not a fixed string, i just put it like this to not distract from the point of the question: the later part of the condition. sorry about the unclear question.

Comment: btw: the person who is to git blame for this left the company 10+ years ago ... x)

Comment: Not just when x is a boolean value, although it's extra pointless in that case.

Comment: @jonrsharpe No, suppose that `x == 5`, then `x != (x and True or False)`.

Comment: You're right, sorry. I was thinking about the context of being in if/while, but it's not true in general.

Answer (score 4):

You can remove **and True or False** from if statement, as it return same result what **someParam != 'nope'** will give.

You can check it by simple example as:

> True and True or False

The output is always **True** Whereas

> False and True or False

The output is always **False**

Answer (score 3):

As you say, the expression `foo and True or False` is just a complicated way of converting the "truthiness" of the value `foo` into an actual boolean:

```
>>> 'foo' and True or False  # non-empty strings are truth-y
True
>>> '' and True or False  # empty strings are false-y
False
```

(You can see the rules for built-in types' truthiness [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).)

This is because `and` and `or` return one of their operands, per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations):

> The expression `x and y` first evaluates *x*; if *x* is false, its
>   value is returned; otherwise, *y* is evaluated and the resulting value
>   is returned.
>
> The expression `x or y` first evaluates *x*; if *x* is true, its value
>   is returned; otherwise, *y* is evaluated and the resulting value is
>   returned.

and, as you say, the [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) for `and` is higher than `or`.

---

That code is totally redundant, for a number of reasons:

1. Because Python already gives you a built-in way to do that, [`bool`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bool):

   ```
   >>> bool('foo')
   True
   >>> bool('')
   False
   ```
2. Because `foo` is already a boolean anyway; `!=` is a comparison, and the result of *any* [comparison](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) is either `True` or `False`, so any conversion to boolean is redundant.
3. Because in a context like `if foo:`, even if `foo` *wasn't* already boolean, Python will *automatically* evaluate the truthiness of `foo` rather than only accepting a boolean, so `if foo and True or False:` and `if bool(foo)` are *both* pointless; you can just write `if foo:`.

---

And no, none of the above points changed between Python 2 and 3. You can check the equivalent links for all of the above in the new version:

- [Truthiness](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)
- [Boolean operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations)
- [Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)
- [`bool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bool)
- [Comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons)

Comment: Aha, i was worried about overlooking something and in fact i was not aware that the `and` and `or` operators return one of the input values instead of a boolean. So thanks for taking the time to write up such a comprehensive answer :>